# inserting multiple _POST values to send to sql table from php web form

Tags: php, mysql

How could I essentially add multiple _POST values to my below statement.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO emails (emailaddress) // starting action

VALUES ('".$_POST['email']."')"; // I would like to add more values to send here
```

Comment: So, what's the desired output?

Comment: are you trying to insert to multiple rows? or more columns in same row ?

Comment: Please, don't do such things... Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You **HAVE** to escape your variable. Read about SQL-injections [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)
2. You can make a foreach statement. Example:
   `foreach($_POST as $emailaddress){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO emails (emailaddress) VALUES (" . $emailaddress . ")";
   // Execute query here.
   }` 
   This codesnippet is just for demonstrational purposes, so do not use it directly. Escape the emailaddress first.